# Update em duas colunas, duas tabelas

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

Tenho que atualizar duas colunas em tabelas distintas, mas não conheço muito bem os comandos para isso, não gostaria de usar triggers(gatilhos).
Serão atualizados em torno de 100 registros.


<sub>Segue um exemplo:</sub>

<sub>**Tabela** **`a`**</sub>

```php
id    nomes  nota
1     SOen   etc1
2     SOpt   etc2
```

<sub>**Tabela** **`b`**</sub>

```php
id    nomes  outros
1     SOen   i
2     SOen   rre
3     SOpt   le
4     SOen   van
5     SOpt   te
```

Ou seja, quando eu atualizar uma row da tabela **`a`** todas as rows com o mesmo nome da tabela **`a`** na tabela **`b`** devem ser atualizados também, ficando com o mesmo nome alterado na tabela **`a`**.

<sub>Exemplo do efeito da atualização desejado:</sub>

```sql
Update a SET nomes = SOpt_BETAP WHERE nomes = SOpt
```

<sub>**Tabela** **`a`**</sub> | *Atualizou a tabela com os novos nomes*

```php
id    nomes       nota
1     SOen        etc1
2     SOpt_BETA   etc2
```

<sub>**Tabela** **`b`**</sub> | *A tabela b também é atualizada com os novos nomes*

```php
id    nomes       outros
1     SOen        i
2     SOen        rre
3     SOpt_BETA   le
4     SOen        van
5     SOpt_BETA   te
```

Seria benéfico para mim e para outros usuários se pudesse fazer uma breve explicação de cada *parâmetro* usado como `ON`, `JOIN` etc, explicando a função dele ali, para quem também tiver duvidas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eu *acho* que é não possível fazer isso com `JOIN` entre as tabelas, pois após o primeiro `UPDATE` em uma das tabelas, o critério do `JOIN` não seria mais atendido ([exemplo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f0c677/1)).

Mas proponho duas alternativas:

#### Alternativa 1: Chave estrangeira na segunda tabela

Se você referenciar os IDs da tabela A na tabela B, em vez de ter os nomes repetidos nas duas tabelas, somente a tabela A precisaria ser atualizada. A tabela B ficaria assim:

```
id    a_id        outros
1     1           i
2     1           rre
3     2           le
4     1           van
5     2           te
```

#### Alternativa 2: Faça dois `UPDATE`s distintos

Não entendi bem o motivo de você querer atualizar as duas tabelas numa operação só. Seria muito mais simples atualizar cada uma separadamente:

```
UPDATE tabelaA SET nomes = 'SOpt BETA' WHERE nomes = 'SOpt';
UPDATE tabelaB SET nomes = 'SOpt BETA' WHERE nomes = 'SOpt';
```

Comment: É uma possibilidade, não sei, para minimizar o numero de conexões, e porque o código ficaria mais limpo. Parece que não é possível né. Eu teria feito isso se achasse que não poderia ser feito em apenas uma query.

Comment: Na verdade eu usaria a Alternativa 1, repetir dados assim me dá coceira!

Comment: Entendo, mas da maneira que fiz, está bom, é como se fosse um id, alterando o nome eu poderia move-lo associando-o a outra tabela etc. É mais simples, vou ter que tomar muito banho pra evitar essa coceira. =)

Comment: Mas você entende que se usar o ID, não é nem necessário atualizar a tabela B? Como o nome só estaria na tabela A, qualquer consulta usando JOIN sempre trará o nome atualizado ao cruzar A com B!

Comment: Entendo sim, mas pra mudar toda uma estrutura no php... Melhor deixar para a próxima. Depois que eu terminar ele, vou pensar nisso, editar a database implica em editar outro código php... é um efeito dominó. Suei só de pensar, mas é possível sim.

Answer (score 1):

Não gosto da ideia mais se tratando de algo já existente você pode fazer o seguinte.
Supondo que o seu banco esteja consistente.

você pode adicionar um índice único a coluna `nomes` na tabela `a`

```sql
alter table a add unique(nomes);
```

e uma chave estrangeira na tabela `b` ligando as tabelas pela coluna`nomes`.
adicionando a cláusula `on update cascade` você está dizendo que quando a coluna `nomes` na tabela pai for atualizada propagar as modificações.

```sql
alter table b add foreign key (nomes) references a(nomes) on update cascade;
```

Assim você vai conseguir atingir seu objetivo de atualizar as duas tabelas com uma única consulta.

Opcionalmente você também pode adicionar a cláusula `on delete cascade` para que quando a o registro pai for deletado remover automaticamente os registros filhos, caso não faça isso será necessário que você remova os registros filhos explicitamente antes de excluir o pai.

```sql
update a set nomes="zaz" where nomes="SOen"
```

veja um exemplo aqui no [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/fa3082/1)

## Alternativa

Resolvi pesquisar um pouco e fazer alguns testes e consegui obter o resultado esperado com a seguinte consulta.

```sql
update a, b set a.nome="zaz", b.nome="zaz" where a.nome="SOen" and b.nome="SOen";
```

Porem foi necessário informar os novos valores e os valores da cláusula `where` explicitamente.

Exemplo no [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/00558c/1)

Comment: Vou verificar em alguns dias, o trabalho está me matando, se tudo der certo essa pode ser a melhor resposta. @hwapx

Comment: Adicionei uma nova alternativa que não acho elegante mais atende a sua necessidade @Florida

Answer (score 0):

Para atualizar os dados da *Tabela* **a** e **b** siga o exemplo:

***Conexão:*** [PHP Data Objects (PDO)](http://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/book.pdo.php)

```php
<?php
    $pdo = new PDO('mysql:dbname=generics;host=localhost', 'root', 'senha', 
                    array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES 'utf8'"));
```

Onde:

- PDO - Interface de acesso a diversos banco de dados com PHP
  No seu construtor possui: `string $dsn, string $username, string $password, 
  array $driver_options`. `$dsn` no caso foi para *Mysql*: `dbname` é o nome do banco de dados e `host` pode ser o **localhost** ou **ip do servidor** de banco de dados, `$username` é o usuário do banco para conexão, `$password` é a senha desse usuário para conexão e `$driver_options` são opções de configurações dessa conexão. Esse [link](http://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/class.pdo.php), possui tudo mais detalhado.

**Código:** com essa conexão usaremos o código a seguir para atualizar as tabelas **a** e **b**

```php
//ATUALIZANDO TABELA 'a'                    
$sts = $pdo->prepare('UPDATE a SET nomes=? WHERE nomes=?');
$sts->bindValue(1, 'SOpt_BETAP', PDO::PARAM_STR);
$sts->bindValue(2, 'SOpt', PDO::PARAM_STR);
$sts->execute();
$sts->closeCursor();
unset($sts);

//ATUALIZANDO TABELA 'b'                    
$sts = $pdo->prepare('UPDATE b SET nomes=? WHERE nomes=?');
$sts->bindValue(1, 'SOpt_BETAP', PDO::PARAM_STR);
$sts->bindValue(2, 'SOpt', PDO::PARAM_STR);
$sts->execute();
$sts->closeCursor();
unset($sts);
```

[$pdo->prepare](http://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/pdo.prepare.php) vai preparar sua `SQL` para receber os paramentos de entrada com [bindValue](http://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/pdostatement.bindvalue.php) seguindo a ordem da esquerda para direita dos `?` e tendo um tipo definido que no caso é `String` ([PDO::PARAM_STR](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.constants.php)). No $sts->execute() ele vai gerar essa `SQL` com os valores e atualizar suas tabelas.

**Ou seja,**

```php
<?php
    $pdo = new PDO('mysql:dbname=generics;host=localhost', 'root', 'senha', 
                    array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES 'utf8'"));

    //ATUALIZANDO TABELA 'a'                    
    $sts = $pdo->prepare('UPDATE a SET nomes=? WHERE nomes=?');
    $sts->bindValue(1, 'SOpt_BETAP', PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $sts->bindValue(2, 'SOpt', PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $sts->execute();
    $sts->closeCursor();
    unset($sts);
    //ATUALIZANDO TABELA 'b'                    
    $sts = $pdo->prepare('UPDATE b SET nomes=? WHERE nomes=?');
    $sts->bindValue(1, 'SOpt_BETAP', PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $sts->bindValue(2, 'SOpt', PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $sts->execute();
    $sts->closeCursor();
    unset($sts);
```

***Só lembrando que não seria a melhor estrutura, ou seja, as tabelas não estão normalizadas.***

Comment: É, acho que terei que usar isso, ou recorrer a gatilhos, você por acaso sabe se o uso deles causa alguma latência apos o update das tabelas ou algo do gênero? @bfavaretto, HarryPotter.

Comment: Eu usaria a alternativa 1 da resposta do @bfavaretto, porque, em apenas um lugar você reflete tal alteração para todos. Em relação aos gatilhos, sinceramente uso bem pouco não gosto muito até prefiro eu controlar as operações do banco, mas, acredito não ter latência não ...

Comment: Vou usar esse método mesmo, qualquer coisa posso recorrer ao gatilho como ultima alternativa. Caso precise mudar o nome de alguma tabela ou coluna fica mais comodo alternar no php, do que ir no gatilho e mudar.

Comment: @Florida nesse ponto dou razão não gosto de gatilho muito não ... mais é gosto no meu entender!